# Слова на букву Ы

Tags: иностранные-слова

Попалось мне на одном сайте такое утверждение: "В русском языке есть слова на «Ы». Это названия российских городов и рек: Ыгыатта, Ыллымах, Ынахсыт, Ыныкчанский, Ытык-кюёль".
Так речь шла об интересных фактах о русском языке. Но, честно говоря, это утверждение меня озадачило: разве тут вообще можно вести речь о русском языке? Эти названия все либо тюркские, либо из языков северных народов, которые просто территориально проживают на территории России. Так при чем тут русский язык?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Но, честно говоря, это утверждение меня озадачило: разве тут вообще можно вести речь о русском языке?

Вполне можно. Понимаете, тут речь идет о фонетике, не о об этимологии заимствований. Вопрос ставится в общем-то так: позволяет ли русская фонетика словам начинаться с Ы? 
И ответ: да, позволяет.

И имена собственные, которые носитель современного русского языка без проблем произнесет и запишет, вполне достаточное тому подтверждениt. А то, что имена эти заимствованные, ничуть тому не помеха.

То, что исконно русские слова с Ы не начинаются, - это тоже факт, но другого порядка. Если уж на то пошло, исконно праславянские слова вообще с гласных не начинаются, таких слов в языке, правда, осталось 2-3%, а всё, что мы имеем - результат либо вторичного фонетического переразложения, либо заимствования, либо упрощения сочетаний с Йотом в начале слова... Русский же звук Ы - результат более позднего фонетического явления в праславянском, он возник в основном на месте индоевропейского U (а русское У в свою очередь - из переразложения сочетаний с W и назальных звуков - но это все на праслявянском этапе), понятно, что с него собственно русские слова начинаться не могут.

В отношении же того, почему все начинающиеся с Ы слова относятся к тюркским и/или палеоазиатским языкам (опустим спорность генеалогии), тоже нет больших сложностей. Передача начального звука заимствования через Ы нужна и возможна только для заимствований из тех языков, где существует оппозиция Ы - И. Таких языков очень немного, поэтому имен нарицательных, даже заимствованных, в русском не появилось, а те, что появились адаптированы под более привычную русским фонетику. Ыстанбул, например, с нарицательными производными стал (посредством европейских) Стамбулом.

***Ырбан*** - поселок в республике Тыва. Ясно, что "не совсем" тюркский (очень далекая ветвь - и вообще классификация спорная) и уж совсем не палеоазиатский. 
Как назвать его жителя? Правильно, ***ырбанец***. Кто скажет, что это ***не русское*** слово, пусть первый бросит в меня камень.

Comment: просто территориально проживают на территории России. 
При чем тут русский язык?

Comment: Кто "проживает на территории"? Слова?

Comment: @shampar, Вы путаете русские слова и слова русского происхождения.

Comment: Не путал, а напомнил вторую часть Вопроса.

Answer (score 5):

Например город Ыб столько лет в составе России, что уже странно говорить о том, что это слово не является русским. Многие слова когда-то заимствовались, приносились в язык извне. Вопрос не в том, считать ли это слово русским. Оно русское. Скорее, можно спросить, является ли это слово исконно русским — тогда можно рассуждать о тюркских корнях. Но на вопрос так, как поставили его вы, ответить можно только однозначно: это слова русские, по крайней мере, сегодня они считаются таковыми.

Answer (score 2):

```
Ввиду того, что произнести сочетания букв "жи" и "ши" через "и" не могут >96% граждан России, (а также - слово "жир (жыр)"), следует считать букву "Ы" российской, издавна вписавшейся в русский язык. Кстати, хорошо бы ей придумать название или, как минимум, вернуть старое название "Юры́", подобно названиям букв в алфавитах других развитых цивилизаций: "Альфа", "Эй", "Ас", "Алеф" и т.д. Подозреваю, что река Иртыш изначально называлась рекой Ыртыш, и лишь из-за страха и нежелания писцов использовать букву "Юры́" она записана как Иртыш.
```

Если посмотреть на историю, то речь любого народа меняется (надеюсь,  эволюционирует) с ходом времени. Буква "Ы" живёт в русском языке давно и является достоянием и духовной драгоценностью русской культуры.
    Кстати, в старинной версии кириллицы есть буква Ѳ (Ѳита, Th-ита), фонетически аналогичная английскому "Th"(ᚦ), по какой-то императорской сиюминутной прихоти изгнанная из алфавита. Сейчас в школах массово учат детей английскому языку. Если бы Ѳиту не отменили рефомой при царях и переводили тексты более умело, то мы бы читали у Толкиена не про Торина Оукщилда, а про Ѳорина Дубощита.

Comment: А оно надо нам, читать Толкиена на языке племени мюмбо-юмбо? Кто хочет - может учит албанский. Или английский. Фиту "отменили" по одной простой причине. Она была совершенна не нужна русской фонетике, только путала. Когда её солунские братья туда добавляли исходили, их нужд переводчиков с греческого. Буква так и осталась невостребованной, наряду с ижицей, включенной туда по тем же соображениям.